# Boostrap popover gets placed outside of window

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Somehow my bootstrap popover outranges the width I gave the containing element.
In fact, it looks like this:
[image: popover-bug]

I initialise the popover like this:

```
$('.filter').popover({
    title: "Anzeigeeinstellungen",
    html: "true",
    placement: "bottom",
    trigger: "click focus",
    content: function(){
      return $('#popoverContent').html();
    },
    container: '#search'
});
```

`#search` has a max-width of 100%

Looking forward for all types of answers:
Force0234

Comment: send some padding to right of that filter icon

Comment: Change the placement to left... Do you have plunker? , it would be easier to see css.

Comment: placement: "left" would probably be the easy fix